# Compare specific child div with parent state data

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to make a karuta style card matching game.
A random card is selected and displayed at the top of the page.
All other cards are displayed below.
The cards are being pulled from a JSON with an `"id" (number), "front" (string), "back" (string)`.

Intended outcome:

- Click lower card.
- If lower card's id(?) == higher card's id, score++,
  generate new cart.

I'm not sure of how to actually compare the two though. How can I get the information from the child component to compare with the parents state? I'm not sure about how to find the 'x' for a specific clicked div here using the handleComparison() function.

> //if (this.props.card[x].id == this.props.currentCard[0].id) {-> score++ - > gen new card}

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "./Header"
import { cardData } from "../Cards";


class GameContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: cardData,
      score: 0,
      currentCard: [{}],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = (e) => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardData.length);
    this.setState({
      currentCard: [cardData[random]]
    })
  }

  handleComparison = (e) => {
    //if (this.props.card[x].id == this.props.currentCard[0].id) -> {score++ - > gen new card}
      console.log('success');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Header score={this.state.score} />
        <div className="currentCard"  >
          <p>{this.state.currentCard[0].front}</p>
        </div>
        <CardContainer cards={this.state.cards} handleComp={this.handleComparison}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class CardContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="CardContainer" className="cardContainer">

                {this.props.cards.map((cards, index) => (
                    <div id="card" className="card" onClick={this.props.handleComp}>
                        <p key={index}>{cards.back}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
                
            </div>);
    }
}
export default GameContainer
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass values from the child component.

```
<CardContainer cards={this.state.cards} handleComp={() => this.handleComparison(whatever_value_you_want_here)}/>
```

then in the parent

```
  handleComparison = (whatever_value_you_want_here) => {
    //if (this.props.card[x].id == this.props.currentCard[0].id) -> {score++ - > gen new card}

      console.log('success', whatever_value_you_want_here);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close to a solution already.
All you need is to pass the props from the child to parent `onClick` of the card

A rewritten code will be

```js
class CardContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="CardContainer" className="cardContainer">

                {this.props.cards.map((card, index) => (
                    <div id="card" className="card" onClick={() => this.props.handleComp(card)}>
                        <p key={index}>{card.back}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
                
            </div>);
    }
}
```

And in the`handleComp` method you save it to the state

```js
class GameContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: cardData,
      score: 0,
      currentCard: [{}],
    }
  }

  // ====

  handleComparison = (card) => {
    //if (card.id == this.state.currentCard[0].id) -> {score++ - > gen new card}
      console.log('success');
  }

  // ====
}
```